# How to use RLMBool property correctly in realm-cocoa?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, realm, realm-mobile-platform

There declared a Bool property in subclasses of RLMObject look like so:

```
@interface PhotoRealm : RLMObject

@property NSNumber<RLMBool> *isVoted;

- (id)initWithMantleModel:(PhotoModel *)photoModel;

@end
```

In .m file ,I have implemented `-defaultPropertyValues` to init like this:

```
+ (NSDictionary *)defaultPropertyValues {
    return @{@"isVoted" : @NO};
}
```

In somewhere, I need to do something by jungle the bool value, but the result is not expected.
Then, I write the following debug code:

```
   if (photoRealm.isVoted) {
        NSLog(@"isVoted");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"unVoted");
    }

    NSLog(@"%ld", (NSInteger)photoRealm.isVoted);
```

log as following:

> [15:32:43] -[DTCollectionViewCell setupContentWithPhotoModel:] [306 line] isVoted
>   [15:32:43] -[DTCollectionViewCell setupContentWithPhotoModel:] [311 line] 4646266992

in the meantime, the snapshot of realm file as so:

[image: the snapshot of realm file]

I'm stuck in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I has resolved it.

Actually, `isVoted` is **NSNumber**,  so the code should like this :

```
if ([photo.isVoted integerValue]) {
        NSLog(@"isVoted");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"unVoted");
    }

    NSLog(@"%ld", [photo.isVoted integerValue]);
```

Comment: Yep! In fact, I believe `NSNumber` also has `[NSNumber boolValue]` to directly check if it's a boolean as well. That being said, you only need to use `NSNumber<RLMBool>` if you explicitly want to be able to set the value to `nil` as well as `true`/`false`. If you just need to be able the set `true` and `false` values, you can also just use `@property BOOL isVoted;` instead as well.

Comment: Nice, I would have thought that "BOOL" can not declared directly in subclass of RLMObject @TiM

Comment: Yep, you can use the normal primitive types in Realm. It's only in Core Data where everything has to be an object. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use it as.

```
if ([photo.isVoted boolValue]) {
    NSLog(@"isVoted");
} else {
    NSLog(@"unVoted");
}
```